Can anyone tell me the package name of Amazon Android App of USA ? Because package name of Amazon app is different for different countries
I need to fire an intent using the package name of Amazon app. But the feature I am building requires to target the amazon app of US region only.
I tried VPN and shared the app link from Google Play Store but it still is giving the Indian package name which is "in.amazon.mShop.android.shopping"

Here is the link for the us play store link.
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.amazon.mShop.android.shopping&hl=en_IN&gl=US
